# setDisable(false) not working on dHTMLX grid cell

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I have a condition to change a cell to be disable when condition A achieved using setDisable(True) and it's working, but on the other hand in others conditions, I have to set the cells of that checkbox to be Enable again so I can check the checkbox (if I make mistakes on input).

Then I tried using setDisable(false) and it's not working. Do you guys have any clue or ways to solve this, because this is not my first time facing this issue, I tried setColumnHidden(false) too and it's not working too.

Here is my code :

```js
if (gridlist.cells(id, 34).getValue() == 0) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "../../index.php/dsMonitoringDemoBooking/Check_Artikel/?st&articleid=" + article_id + "&TerminCode=" + TerminCode,
    success: function(e) {
      var _e = JSON.parse(e);
    
      if (_e.flagPrd == 'N' && _e.flagTrm == 'N') { 
        alert(_e.message);
        alert(_e.message2);
        gridlist.cells(id, 34).setDisabled(true);
      } else if (_e.flagPrd == 'N' && _e.flagTrm == 'Y') { 
        alert(_e.message);
        gridlist.cells(id, 34).setDisabled(true);
      } else if (_e.flagPrd == 'Y' && _e.flagTrm == 'N') {
        alert(_e.message2);
        gridlist.cells(id, 34).setDisabled(true);
      } else if (_e.flagPrd == 'Y' && _e.flagTrm == 'Y') { 
        gridlist.cells(id, 34).setDisabled(false); //this is the problem
      }

    }


  });
}
```

here you can see the table grid :
[image]

*the checkbox will be disabled depending on article and termin value. If I give the right value on article and wrong value on Termin, it will be disabled. But when I change the termin to be the right value, it's not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I remove some line code and reread all the condition in this function, then I found the condition that I don't recognize it.

My new code is :

```js
function CheckCashback(terminId) {

  var selectedId = gridlist.getSelectedRowId();
  var article_id = gridlist.cells(selectedId, 3).getValue();
  var TerminCode = terminId;
  
  //I removed the condition >> if (gridlist.cells(id, 34).getValue() == 0) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "../../index.php/dsMonitoringDemoBooking/Check_Artikel/?st&articleid=" + article_id + "&TerminCode=" + TerminCode,
    success: function(e) {
      var _e = JSON.parse(e);
      if (_e.flagPrd == 'N' && _e.flagTrm == 'N') {
        alert(_e.message);
        alert(_e.message2);
        gridlist.cells(selectedId, 34).setDisabled(true);
      } else if (_e.flagPrd == 'N' && _e.flagTrm == 'Y') {
        alert(_e.message);
        gridlist.cells(selectedId, 34).setDisabled(true);
      } else if (_e.flagPrd == 'Y' && _e.flagTrm == 'N') {
        alert(_e.message2);
        gridlist.cells(selectedId, 34).setDisabled(true);
      } else {// and at least this code is work fine
        gridlist.cells(selectedId, 34).setDisabled(false);
      }
    }


  });

}
```

That line " if (gridlist.cells(id, 34).getValue() == 0) {" and forEachRow looping, I think it's useful for getting the condition of disbled cells. But actually it ruined. Thanks for all your kind answer.